# className={ validatorState === RIGHT ? 'ok' : 'no' }

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I would like to add a different class depending on the validation in react.

Currently I have

```
className={ validatorState === RIGHT ? 'ok' : 'no' }
```

But I also need something like

```
className={ validatorState === WRONG ? 'ok' : 'yes' }
```

How do I do that inside the same className?

Comment: will there be the situations both RIGHT and WRONG and if there is that kind of scenarios which className do you need to put.

Comment: Yes, for example, if RIGHT I want to put class yes, if WRONG I want to put class no. But if validates at the same time something like: className={ (validatorState === RIGHT? 'ok' : 'yes' ) , (validatorState === WRONG ? 'ok' : 'no' ) } but this does not work

Comment: In that case your code sample is contradictory to your last comment. Your sample said that if 'RIGHT' then 'ok', and now you're saying if 'RIGHT' then 'yes'

Answer (score 3):

I do not understand exactly what you are trying to achieve as the conditions overlap.

> Yes, for example, if RIGHT I want to put class yes, if WRONG I want to
> put class no. But if validates at the same time something like:
> className={ (validatorState === RIGHT? 'ok' : 'yes' ) ,
> (validatorState === WRONG ? 'ok' : 'no' ) } but this does not work –
> lopezi 1 hour ago

Looking at your comment above, in order to explain how you could handle the logic for adding the className, I will assume that for **RIGHT you want the class 'yes'**, for **WRONG you want the class 'no'** and for **everything else you want the class 'ok'**.

Adding a lot of logic in the className can make the code hard to read.
What you could do is extract the logic in a separate variable or even function if the logic is complicated and cannot be written in a single line. It depends on the exact logic you need.

**Variable**

```
const cx = validatorState === RIGHT ? 'yes' : validatorState === WRONG ? 'no' : 'ok'
```

**Function**

```
const getClassName = (validatorState) => {

  if (validatorState === RIGHT) {
    return "yes";
  }

  if (validatorState === RIGHT) {
    return "no";
  }

  return ok;
};
```

And then

```
<div className={getClassName(validatorState)}></div>
```

**classnames**

I suggest looking into [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames), a very popular package used for conditionally applying and joining classes together. You could do something like this:

```
import classnames from 'classnames';

....

const cx = classnames({
  ok: validatorState !== RIGHT && validatorState !== WRONG,
  yes: validatorState === RIGHT,
  no: validatorState === WRONG,
});

...

<div className={cx}></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Passing list of class names to prop.
like `className={'ok,no'}`

```
const classes = [
  ...new Set([
    validatorState === RIGHT ? "ok" : "no",
    validatorState === WRONG ? "ok" : "yes",
  ]),
].join();

className = { classes };
```